# Axis sending soap messages with HTTP 1.0 and receiving HTTP 1.1 soap calls

Tags: java, http, soap, axis

I'm new to web services and soap so I am likely to make newb mistakes.  The project I am working on sends and receives soap messages from a server (I can't modify the server configuration). The server uses Axis 1.4 and I have generated my client stubs also with Axis 1.4,  I want to use HTTP 1.1 persistent connections so I configured Axis to use [Apache HTTP Common Library](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).  I configured Axis using the examples documented at [site 1](http://wiki.apache.org/ws/FrontPage/Axis/AxisCommonsHTTP), [site 2](http://old.nabble.com/Axis-1.4-configuration-to-use-HTTP-1.1-td13014221.html), and [site 3](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/pfwiki.nsf/dx/10022008035400PMWEBRCB.htm).  Now when I make a soap call it sends the soap message using HTTP 1.0 and receives the message using HTTP 1.1.  Does anybody know why I am still sending messages using HTTP 1.0 instead of HTTP 1.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include the modified axis jar in my projects class path. After that I could send and receive messages using HTTP 1.1.